# AngularJS search multiple keywords using one field

Tags: angularjs, search, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I am new to AngularJS. I have 3 input fields to enter up to 3 keywords for a single post:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Keyword1"></input>
<input type="text" ng-model="Keyword2"></input>
<input type="text" ng-model="Keyword3"></input>
```

I am displaying the posts using ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: searchKeyword"
...
```

and searching by:

```
Search Keyword: <input ng-model="searchKeyword.Keyword1">
```

As you can see, this currently only searches the first keyword of every post. How can I have only one search field that searches all three keywords of a post? I know I cannot just do

```
<input ng-model="searchKeyword.Keyword1.Keyword2.Keyword3">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the intention is to return all posts that match at least one keyword or all posts that match all keywords. Here is how you could create a custom filter for matching at least one word:

```
<div ng-controller="theController">
  <input ng-model="inputText"/>
  <!-- Use a custom filter to determine which posts should be visible -->
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:myFilter">{{post}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

angular.module('theApp', [])
  .controller('theController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputText = 'test';
    $scope.posts = [
      'test test2;lksdf asdf one asdf poo',
      'arm test test2 asdf',
      'test head arm chest'
    ];

    $scope.myFilter = function(post) {
      // default to no match
      var isMatch = false;

      if ($scope.inputText) {
        // split the input by space
        var parts = $scope.inputText.split(' ');

        // iterate each of the words that was entered
        parts.forEach(function(part) {
          // if the word is found in the post, a set the flag to return it.
          if (new RegExp(part).test(post)) {
            isMatch = true;
          }
        });
      } else {
        // if nothing is entered, return all posts
        isMatch = true;
      }

      return isMatch;
    };
  }]);
```

And here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/d17dZDrlhY2KIfWCbKyZ?p=preview

NOTE: this solution does not limit the keywords to 3. Any number of keywords can be entered, separate by the space character. If nothing is entered (or just spaces), everything is returned.

Comment: How do you do when its an object of keys?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i will do

1. write a custom filter  (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)
2. in  filter split the input by space (which will give you separate words)
3. search all words in input one by one